# Unity UI Not Showing up

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine

So I have created two new projects just to see if that would change anything but it didn't. So what I do is have a canvas that is on the whole screen and I right click and add a button or dropdown, I haven't tried other UI. But when I do this the button is created and everything is marked as it showing text but no text is shown. I resized the button and font size but still no text. I didn't have this issue in my last few projects but now idk whats wrong or how to fix this. Any help?

Comment: Maybe you need to post screenshot of the hierarchy and inspector of the canvas and the UI object you want to show. It's nearly impossible to help you with just texts in your question.

Comment: no thats not the problem everything should work I just opened an old project but it doesn't show anything in my assets but has one of the scenes open and all the ui text isn't showing so something is wrong with unity i just don't know how to fix @Programmer

Comment: Sometimes the UI DLL files seem to get lost. We have a script to reimport just those, but you might try a reimport all or maybe delete your Library directory and reopen the project.

Comment: whats the script and what do you mean by reimport all? or delete library? @RetiredNinja

Comment: There's a menu item under Assets to Reimport All, and the Library directory is next to your project directory on disk.

Answer (score -1):

There is some problem with the UI in the previous versions of Unity. This has been fixed in the latest version of Unity. Update Unity and UI will work fine.